# Как сделать нумерацию списка пользователей

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать нумерацию списка?

**Вот код:**

```
for first, last, nickname, user_id in Cursor.fetchall():

        num0 = 1
        num1 = int(num0) + 1
        mess += str(num1) + '' + f"@id{user_id}({first}\t{last}) - \t{nickname}" + '\n'

    vk.messages.send(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        message=mess,
    )
```

**Вывод:**

```
2 Пользователь 
2 Пользователь
2 Пользователь
```

Что не так?

Comment: строчку `num0 = 1` вынести выше цикла не пробовали ?

Comment: @S.Nick, вынес. И что дальше?

Comment: Дальше инкрементируй `num0` в цикле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так?

```
for num, (first, last, nickname, user_id) in enumerate(Cursor.fetchall()):
    mess += f"{num}@id{user_id}({first}\t{last}) - \t{nickname}" + '\n'
```

`enumerate` - означает "пронумеровать". Работает это так:

```
for n, (x, y) in enumerate([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]):
    print(n, ':', x, y)
```

Результат:

```
0 : 1 2
1 : 3 4
2 : 5 6
```